# The operation has timed out when i run without use breakpoints

Tags: c#, .net, timeout

I try run my code. If i use debug works. But if i don't use debug i always recive the erro  "The operation has timed out". I was recive this erro in a line where i make a Http request, but later i update the erro change line.

My StackTrace is:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(XmlReader reader, XmlSpace space)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.Compiler.LoadDocument(XmlTextReaderImpl reader)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load(String url)
   at eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Abaco.Crawling.Base.AbacoWSCrawlerBaseV2.<GetRangeItemsAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\tfs\Trunk\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Abaco\Crawling\Base\AbacoWSCrawlerBaseV2.cs:line 225
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Abaco.Crawling.V2.AbacoDFePrestadaCrawlerV2.<ExecuteCoreAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\tfs\Trunk\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Abaco\Crawling\V2\AbacoDFePrestadaCrawlerV2.cs:line 24
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Commom.CrawlerBase.<ExecuteAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\tfs\Trunk\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Commom\Services\Base\CrawlerBase.cs:line 29
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Commom.Web.WebCrawlerBase.<ExecuteAsync>d__19.MoveNext() in C:\tfs\Trunk\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Commom\Web\WebCrawlerBase.cs:line 45
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Commom.Web.PreAuthenticatedWSCrawlerBase.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\tfs\Trunk\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler\eNotasGW.DFe.Crawler.Application.Commom\Web\PreAuthenticatedWSCrawlerBase.cs:line 75
```

In my file AbacoWSCrawlerBaseV2 in line 225 i have :

```
var xslTransform = new XslTransform();
var pdfResponseLink = new Uri(BaseUri, Url.Combine(RelativePath, "../schemas/nfse/nfse_v204.xsl"));
xslTransform.Load(pdfResponseLink.ToString());
```

I load a link in xslTransform.

Whats this is happening?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with excessive asynchronous code. Are keeping your code synchronous up to the top level?

Comment: I agree with @Nigel, you likely need an await somewhere. When you hit the breakpoint, another task might be executing. When you run like normal, that other task isn't given the opportunity to complete its job.

Comment: I will check your observations